# Redis transaction pipeline is not carrying out all transactions and instead returning QUEUED commands

Tags: go, redis, transactions

Go redis transaction pipeline, is not carrying out all transactions and instead returning QUEUED commands when pipe.Exec() is called.

(Redis client used: "github.com/go-redis/redis/v7" imported as red)

When the length of keys > 9, the cmders struct from pipe.Exec() returned is an array where the first element is of type *redis.StatusCmd, with the val "QUEUED"  and the data "multi". The rest of the elements are of type *redis.StringStringMapCmd as expected.

```
    pipe := *red.Client.TxPipeline()

    for _, key := range keys {

        pipe.HGetAll(key)
    }

    cmders, err := pipe.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Additional Information/things I tried:

- All errors are nil
- When len(keys) = 10 the last command in the pipeline is not executed and is instead QUEUED; the cmders array contained 1 *redis.StatusCmd and 9 *redis.StringStringMapCmd structs corresponding to the first 9 keys.
- Increasing the number of keys, results in more commands being missed.
  For example when the length of keys was 70, there were no
  *redis.StringStringMapCmd structs returned for the last 7 commands.
- The same problem was found to occur when using HDEL, HGET and HSET.
- Adding a time.Sleep() before and after the Exec did not change
  anything either.
- Finally I tried rearranging the keys array and found the same
  problem, the last command added to the pipeline was QUEUED.